# SSRS Date Parameter Not working

Tags: reporting-services

I have two parameters for the report "StartDate" and "EndDate" respectively.
They work fine in the chart filter expressions , however when I use the same in the series expression as CDate(Parameters!Startdate.Value) > CDate(Fields!InAck.value) of the chart to compare against a date column in the dataset and calculate the series value for datediff, it doesn't return the values promptly .